# Are events correlated in a Poisson distribution?

Tags: statistics, poisson-distribution

I would like some input on a discussion I am currently having with a colleague regarding some measurements that were done recently.

I have some radiation physics data that is processed as a histogram. This histogram I believe can be modeled as a Poisson distribution since each value that goes into a given interval, or bin, is independent of any other. My colleague is arguing that this thinking is incorrect, but rather, bins that are **closer together** in the histogram are correlated, and as a result I am over-estimating the amount of error in my measurements.

Is this correct? To me, the formulation of a histogram is simply an intuitive data processing technique, wherein there is no "cross-talk" between bins.

There is obviously quite a bit of overlap here with regard to physics, so I will resort to analogy for the lay person: We are breaking-up heavy ions using shielding of varying types. We could refer to the heavy ion fragments as pieces of "mail", the detector as the "mailbox", a histogram bin as the "delivery day", and the total number of bins containing all the mail as the "month". Of course, integration over the histogram bins gives the total amount of mail delivered in a month. The peak delivery day in a given month is dependent on the amount of shielding between the beam and the detector. Following this analogy, my colleague is arguing that any two delivery days are correlated.

Comment: I think you are right. Radioactive decay is the classic Poisson process. The histogram is just a data visualization tool.

Comment: I would say that it depends on the underlying processes. If your observation is a superposition of two effects you would have a problem in using the histogram. E.g. some nuclear active atoms tend to decay in a special sequence. So it primarily depends on the underlying physics.

Comment: @JoelDeWitt Not an expert in this field :D. But if an ion breaks with more intensity can it be reflected by the shielding? That would intensify the frequency of breaking ... (interpret everything that I say from the perspective of a child that does not know anything about physics #NotAPhysisct :D). I am thinking about the double slit experiment, which also influences the distribution of particles on the shield. Also if something breaks off will it not be less likely to break something off again from the same atom because the excitation is reduced?

Comment: @MachineLearner, I have updated my question with an analogy to make it easier to understand.